Singular Values in The Singular Values Decomposition
The SVD has a mathematical expression as follows
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{V}^T,
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{A}\in{m\times n}$, $\mathbf{U}\in{m\times m}$, $\mathbf{\Sigma}\in{m\times n}$, $\mathbf{V}\in{n\times n}$. $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ are an orthogonal matrix. $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a matrix whose non-zero elements in the leading one position are the square root of eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$.
Is there any method to create matrix $\mathbf{A}$ whose all elements are an integer and covariance, $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$, results in positive integer and/or zero eigenvalues?
Note that matrix $\mathbf{A}$ shouldn't be a diagonal matrix

look for orthogonal matrices with rational entries

Can you give an example of such matrices? Because if we set up an orthogonal matrix with rational entries for \mathbf{U} and \mathbf{V}, it will not be certain whether the matrix A could be an all-integer entries matrix.

no, but if $\Sigma$ is integer, then an opportune multiple of $A$ will be integer

Thanks for the insight. How about we create a positive semi-definite matrix whose all entries and all eigenvalues are integers? I believe we can construct $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ from there. entries in $\Sigma$ can also be obtained from the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^T$. The most important question is that how to construct such positive semi-definite matrix?

I think Exxod is saying that it will be easier to construct the orthogonal matrix with rational entries first. For example, if you do a QR factorization on a matrix of integers, every step in the factorization process is a rational operation, so the Q matrix will contain rational entries.
